# Cardinality of recursive relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, recursion, erd, cardinality

I have created a database for Computing in Schools (CIS) and i have some extra requirements to add from the below information. I created an ERD but feel like i have made a few mistakes such as the cardinality of the recursive relationship?

Any other feedback would be appreciated.

**New Requirements**
CiS would like to use the database to share the details of sessions, participants, etc., online through a web site. Anyone involved – student volunteer, school staff, SHU lecturers – will be able to login with a username (or maybe an email address) and a password. Once logged in, members use the site differently (school staff to request sessions, SHU lecturers to manage them, and student volunteers to see what they can take part in, confirm their availability, and check afterwards that the hours are right).
CiS want to be able to share resources via the site. Resources are files that are useful in sessions or generally to CiS’ purpose. Members who create such files upload them, and the database holds such details as the URL, the file title, a description, and keep track of the file’s author.
Members can upload files, members can tag them, give them a star rating, and comment them.

•   **Tags** are keywords that users assign to a file. A file can have multiple tags; once someone has tagged a file with a keyword, there is no need for anyone else to mark the same file with the same keyword again.

•   **Star rating**. Any site member can rate any file, but not re-rate a file that they have rated.

•   **Comments** have no such limits, because ultimately they form a discussion about each file, so site members can write many comments about the files. It will be helpful to know the date, author and subject of every file comment.

[image: Additional requirements ERD!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagram is not an ERD. In particular, the use of lines to represent relationships restricts you to binary relationships, and loses much of the expressive power of the Entity-Relationship model.

By using the combination of `Username` and `Password` as primary keys in your users tables, you allow the possibility that different users can use the same `Username` with different passwords. Is this what you want? However, in the `Upload file` table, you only store the `Author_username`, so perhaps you want only the `Username` as key? You need to be consistent here.

Your `Uploaded file` table needs to be broken into many. At the moment, it supports only one tag, one rating and one comment per file/username. It's not clear whether the `Author_username` indicates the user who uploaded the file or the user that tagged, rated and commented on a file. BTW, those things are linked together in your table, preventing a user from posting more tags or comments than ratings. The `File title` and `File description` are probably dependent only on `File URL` and will be duplicated if multiple tags, ratings or comments are stored, leading to a risk of inconsistency.

Edit:

Since you asked for recommendations in your comment, I suggest:

1. Use Chen's ERD notation, or at least a variation that uses shapes to represent relationships and supports ternary and higher relationships. An even better approach would be [Object-Role Modeling](http://orm.net).
2. Use only `Username` as the primary key for your 4 user tables.
3. Split `Uploaded file` into the following tables:

   - `Uploaded file (File_URL PK, File_title, File_description, Username FK)`
   - `File_tags (File_URL PK/FK, Tag PK)`
   - `File_ratings (File_URL PK/FK, Username PK/FK, Rating)`
   - `File_comments (Comment_ID PK, File_URL FK, Username FK, Comment, Created_at, Reply_to_comment_ID FK)`

Note that this is just a minimal set of changes to address the issues I raised, meant for educational purposes, not necessarily a proper solution to your requirements.

Comment: ok thank you, so would you recommend to:
1. change author_username to username
2. create a new link table going from user info to uploaded file?
3. This would include the attributes such as file_comment and file_rating?

Comment: I edited my post to add suggestions. Let me know if you have any questions about them.

Comment: 1. I am unable to use any other way of apart from the way i have drawn.
2. So how would the user table be linked to the uploaded file, if i have no (Username FK) in the uploaded file table?
3. File_comments would be linked to the user table aswell as the uploaded file table?

Comment: Also for file comments, would you recommend removing (Reply_to_comment FK) or does this need to be here to trigger a reply to the files comments?

Comment: 1. Even so, understanding the issues in the design can help to find ways to limit the risks. 2. Apologies, I fixed my suggestion to include `Username FK`. 3. Yes, you want to record who commented as well as what file they commented on. 4. If you're ok with a flat list (as opposed to a hierarchy) of comments, you can remove it.